# How to customize drop down arrow in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, hide

I used this:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

But it only works in IE10.

I need this for IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://selectivizr.com/ to get the latest css3 for IE9 and bellow.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[JS library]"></script>
 <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->
```

Good Luck!